How can I view if I have a resource in a given location in Azure?
When I go to https://portal.azure.com/, I see all my resources, but unless I click on one of them, I don't see which location their deployed. How can I view if I have a resource in a given location in Azure without having to click on each of them one by one? If that matters, I'm interested in Azure OpenAI resources.

By location, I'll assume you mean region. If that's the case then select the location filter under all resources and select the region you're interested in.

